# authconfig: command not found ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, hash

I'm trying to use hashcat to validate a hashing algorithm but keeping this error when using authconfig command.

```
error: authconfig: command not found ubuntu
```

Am I missing something?  I haven't installed ldap but the server is configured as LAMP.

Answer (score 1):

`authconfig` is not packaged with Ubuntu 14.04. You can use SSSD (System Security Services Daemon (SSSD) instead. I found [this](https://www.ossramblings.com/Ubuntu-14.04-SSSD-and-OpenLDAP-Authentication) useful.

Comment: SSSD is not a replacement for authconfig and authconfig is useful even with SSSD installed and configured.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/676284/home-dir-and-shell-for-active-directory-authenticated-users

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install ldap-auth-config
```

will generate a user-interactive prompt that will ask for your LDAP server name or IP and port number as well as the CN, OU and DC information.

I can only speak to Bionic Beaver as that's what I currently work with.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use `authconfig` command to set up SHA-256/512 hashing. This command provides a simple method of configuring `/etc/sysconfig/network` to handle NIS, as well as `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`, the files used for shadow password support. Basic LDAP, Kerberos 5, and SMB (authentication) client configuration is also provided.
Type the following command:

```
authconfig --test | grep hashing
```

Configure Linux Server To Use The SHA-512 algorithm

To configure the Linux system to use the SHA-512 algorithm, enter:

```
authconfig --passalgo=sha512 --update
```

Note: users need to change their passwords in order to generate hashes using SHA-512. You can force users to change their password on next login:

```
change -d 0 userName
```

Comment: He is asking why the command is not found, not what to do with it.

Comment: The OP has asked something else, and what you are answering I am not really quite sure. Consider, editing the answer.